# Magento upgrade gives pearmage.php not found?

Tags: upgrade

I'm trying to update magento 1.4.0 to 1.7 for a client.
first I installed magento from the host server to my local server for test purpose. 
I have windows 7/cygwin.
when I try to execute the command `./pear mage-setup` I get the following
 [image]

I have been working around this issue but I haven't found anything yet.

Comment: I have no idea how to solve THIS problem, but I update normally by just replacing the magento core with a new one. If you have windows, you can just copy it over and everything is done.

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt - what about the database then?!

Comment: If you replace the core files, the local.xml remains and the update scripts are updating the db.

Comment: Just to be certain, *`/cygdrive/c/Apache24/htdocs/downloader/pearlib/php/pearmage.php`* exists & has correct permissions, yes?

Comment: @benmarks - yes it does exist and it has 777 permission :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely your problem isn't the file missing/permissions etc. But the fact you are using CygWin and Windows, `set PATH` may not function the same way as it would on a real Linux system.

Take a closer look into what the `./pear` command is actually doing:

- https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.4-beta/pear

Bottom of the code you'll notice the call for `pearmage.php`:

```
exec $PHP -C -q $INCARG -d output_buffering=1 -d variables_order=EGPCS \
    -d open_basedir="" -d safe_mode=0 -d register_argc_argv="On" \
    -d auto_prepend_file="" -d auto_append_file="" \
    $INCDIR/pearmage.php -c $PEAR_INI "$@
```

Validate your `include_path` in PHP with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and ensure it will include the `downloader/pearlib/php/;` directory.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php

Related StackOverflow Question:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556780/why-wont-pear-work-on-my-php-windows-installation

For reference of the file missing in question:

- https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.4-beta/downloader/pearlib/php/pearmage.php

Ultimately as Fabian Blechschmidt mentioned, Simply copying the new codebase over the files will be much easier than trying to go through the pear channels.  DB Upgrades will trigger after the new files are copied and a front/backend request is made.

Also consider setting up a Virtual Machine on a true Linux stack if your getting down to the Bash/Perl level of things.

Comment: Well-said: thank you for a thoughtful answer.

Comment: thank you for such a detailed answer. and please excuse my urge to ask you this but, after copying the core file, what do you mean by the database will trigger the upgrade. Note: the case here is that some programmer 4 years ago did this project and now they asked me to upgrade it. so I copied the files from their server and I'm working on localhost. so might I be missing any files to?!
about working on linux. yes I'm a linux user but it's a temporary solution for me to use cygwin due to some mess.
thanks again

Comment: Audit the community & local code pools for any 3rd party modules, diff the existing 1.4.x codebase with a similar vanilla install.  This should give you enough insight on what the other developer did. As for the DB upgrade after question: http://goo.gl/bCqFM

Answer (score 2):

The `pear` command is no longer included in the 1.7 package, this has been replaced by the `mage` command.

Comment: First thanks for your answer.
and yes, I know that. the version I have is 1.4.0 not 1.7

Comment: Sorry, thought that this problem occoured after the upgrade. Do you have the file downloader/pearlib/php/pearmage.php? You could try to copy that directory from the original dowload zip file. It looks like that there are some files missing.

Comment: hey, yes I have the file for sure. and yes I tried copying it from the original one also. it's the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Step by step, did you do the following commands before `mage-setup` command?

```
// run the following commands in Magento root directory
$ ./pear upgrade PEAR
$ ./pear update-channels
```

Also, and BIG also, get rid of cygwin first!